# Can I get some basic protection of a test website in Firebase Hosting?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

Since HTTP auth seems impossible on Firebase Hosting, is there a quick hack like the "obfuscating folder" here: [Github Auth Proxy](https://github.com/comsysto/github-pages-basic-auth-proxy#-create-the-obfuscator-directory-in-your-gh-pages-branch) to protect my app source code pre release?

Like changing some rewrites in firebase.json?

I tried stuff like this (which does not work):

```
"rewrites": [
  {
    "source": "**",
    "destination": "/uselessIndex.html"
  },
  {
    "source": "/supersecretFolder",
    "destination": "/index.html"
  }
]
```

Btw.: The recommended solution is a bit overkill for my purposes: [Protect with Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to "protect" any content deployed to Firebase Hosting.  Once deployed, the content is all accessible for anyone who knows the URL.  There is no obfuscation.